# Getting an error while Connecting to APNS server

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

source: www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Terminal Command:

> Initiums-iMac:Desktop initium$ openssl s_client -connect
>   gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
>       -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem

Terminal Response:

> CONNECTED(00000003)   depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust,
>   Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009
>   Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
>
> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
>   verify return:0
>
> 3122:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.2/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1106:SSL
>   alert number 40
>
> 3122:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake
>   failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.2/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:

Answer (score 0):

Following the tutorial www.raywenderlich.com/32960, I think I faced the same issue... almost.

Anyways, I think it was because I had goofed up with the .p12 file specifically.

Did you export the correct private key from inside "**Keychain Access > Keys**"?
This part comes under "**Generating the Certificate Signing Request (CSR)**" where you have to export the private key as a p12 file.

Delete all the unnecessary certificates and keys, start from scratch and closely follow the tutorial.

Comment: yeah, i done all that. i export my .p12 file at desktop. can u please help me from this situation. thanks in advance

Comment: i'll try to help.  
did you run the command:  
`curl -O https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_2048_ca.cer`?

Comment: nitiums-iMac:Desktop initium$ curl -O https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_2048_ca.cer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1500  100  1500    0     0    780      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  1300
it is showin like this

Comment: it's not easy for me to zero down on your particular issue. it'll be easier just to trash everything: the csr, the cer, the p12, the pem, the provisioning profile and start fresh.

Comment: Can i come again from starting onwards.Am i right.I have to create new app id or the same.I have one question when i'm export private key it is asking some message like this."Enter a password which will be used to protect export items". what is this? And another question is what is pass phrase and what i have to enter. suppose i'm entering pass phrase means it is saying that verifying and again asking enter pem pass phrase. thanks in advance

Comment: App ID can be same but in my case, i had messed up with the certificates that i had sent to apple and the one i was using on the server (i was just confused with it all) and so I trashed the App ID and made a new one and ensured that I was providing the correct certificate.
anyways, since you are exporting a **private** key, it's asking if you want to password protect it. You can enter anything you like here or leave it totally blank (no issues... but it's better you specify a passphrase).